# Boost.Python list all exposed classes and attributes

Tags: python, c++, boost

I am exposing classes from C++ to Python using Boost.Python, for example:

```
class_<Point>("Point").
        def(init<double, double, double>()).
        add_property("X", &Point::GetX, &Point::SetX).
        add_property("Y", &Point::GetY, &Point::SetY).
        add_property("Z", &Point::GetZ, &Point::SetZ).
        def("SetXYZ", &Point::SetPnt);
```

I am also exposing some variables as attributes of my main module:

```
MainModule.attr("Window") = object(ptr(mainWindow));
```

Is it possible to list all exposed classes and/or all attributes of a module (in C++)?

I expect to get a list (`vector<string>`) of all exposed classes: in this case just "Point". The same for exposed variables, in this case just "Window".

Comment: I don't see how is that a duplicate

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, what do you mean by C++ module tho?

Comment: It is not a C++ module, but a module object made this way: `object MainModule = import("___main___");`

Answer (score 0):

Using Python reflection capabilities:

Executing some code from C++:

```
PyRun_SimpleString("import inspect");
PyRun_SimpleString("import MyModule");
string getClassesCode =
    "def GetClasses():\n"
    "    for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(MyModule):\n"
    "        if inspect.isclass(obj):\n"
    "            yield obj.__name__\n"
    "_classes = list(GetClasses())\n";


    typedef boost::python::list pylist;
    object main_namespace = MainModule.attr("__dict__");

    try
    {
        exec(getClassesCode.c_str(), main_namespace);
    }
    catch (error_already_set  const &)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    pylist _classes = extract<pylist>(main_namespace["_classes"]);

    for (int i = 0; i < len(_classes); ++i)
    {
        string className = extract<string>(_classes[i]);
        //do whatever you need with the class name
    }
```

Comment: I think I may have gotten you wrong here... Didn't you mean you want to use C++ code from inside your python code?? This snippet seems like you're doing the opposite, i.e. importing some python classes into your C++ code? I think what threw me off was the "exposing classes *from C++ to Python*" part...

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist Yes, but this is unrelated, I'm just using Python's introspection capabilities to get all classes and then send that info to C++. The classes exposition from C++ to Python has been done before, and it is not posted here (due to its length and because it is irrelevant)

Comment: Still feel like I'm not entirely with you -- you're saying the exposition from C++ to Python is irrelevant but again I thought the original question was *exactly* about how to do that. Hence my suggestion was clearly a solution to this specific requests...

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to list all exposed classes and/or all attributes of a
>   module (in C++)? I expect to get a list (`vector<string>`) of all exposed classes ...

I'm not aware of such a feature of Boost.Python, but one alternative, carrying an overhead though, might be to expose a list (you can have it `std::vector<string>`, why not?) that you prepare "manually" on the C++ side and maintain it as you change your exposure composition. That way, you only have to know the name such list *or lists* and import them initially to get such a functionality.

Comment: What you are proposing is to do it manually and that is not what I need

Comment: @Sturm Fully agree with you it is a manual solution, I never said otherwise. On the contrary, all I meant was that it might serve your purpose in the absence of a built-in alternative. Was going for practicality here, as this solution takes minimal time to implement and maintain. Am I wrong here?

Comment: I can think of many situations where that is not the case. Imagine a third party plugin developer for my application that wants to expose his objects to this python scripting engine and have all features that main application has (available classes in this case, but not limited to that, the actual purpose was to extract method signatures to help the user writing python code). And in anyway that would be basically duplicating all my exposition code to a) expose to python b) add to a list of strings

Comment: @Sturm OK, just so I get this straight, in the given scenario, you'd like the 3rd party developer to have his exposed entities be a part of the original singular list, so that the python code could remain the same, not having to know the name of further lists and importing them as well, right?

Comment: @Sturm OK, I'm with you I think : ) Question: do you see a problem with having the plugins let the main module know about all of their exposed objects?